# Meteor helpers not working in each loop

Tags: javascript, meteor

What should seem rather elementary is not working properly for me. I'm simply trying to show a list of announcements on a dashboard, but my helper does not seem to pull the data from the publication. My files are below.

publications.js

```
Meteor.publish('announcements', function() {
    return Announcements.find();
});
```

Template JS (dashboard.js):

```
Template.sendersDashboard.helpers({
    announcements: function() {
        return Announcements.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
    }
})
```

View JS (dashboard.html):

```
<template name="dashboard_announcements">
    {{#each announcements}}
        {{> single_announcement}}
    {{else}}
        There are no Announcements to display.
        <br>
        <h5><a href="{{pathFor 'newAnnouncement'}}">Why don't you make one now?</a></h5>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

When I view the page in the browser I only see the `{{else}}`case. I've checked the database and can see records available. Plus I am receiving no errors at all regarding the calls.

Any help, suggestions, etc. is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you subscribe properly? Try Announcements.find().fetch() in console and see if it returned empty array

Comment: Thanks @Sindis. Looks like I was not fetching correctly. Via lehtu below, I was missing a subscription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like Sindis suggested, you might be missing the subscription in your dashboard.js.

```
Meteor.subscribe('announcements');
```

Or another thing could be that you are having helper in wrong template. Instead of:

```
Template.sendersDashboard.helpers({...
```

You should have:

```
Template.dashboard_announcements.helpers({...
```

Comment: Thanks @lehtu. I was missing my subscription in the controller. You are correct about the different name of the templates, but that's because the the dashboard_announcements is nested in the sendersDashboard. Thanks much.

Comment: I thought you could have something like that, but you can never know in here :) Happy to help you!

Answer (score 0):

You have different template name in your JS and HTML:

Your template name in JS is `sendersDashboard`:

```
Template.sendersDashboard.helpers({
   //code
});
```

And your template name in HTML is `dashboard_announcements`:

```
<template name="dashboard_announcements">
  <!-- code -->
</template>
```

I recommend to use camelCase names of your templates, so fix the HTML name:

```
<template name="sendersDashboard">
  <!-- code -->
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks, too. I've changed to camelCase, too. Too much of the ruby world still stuck in my head.